# Formmating ejs in visual studio code

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, indentation, ejs

Hi, I need to indent my ejs code in visual studio, but I get this message:
"Sorry, but there is no formatter for 'ejs'-files installed"

I already installed EJS Language Support but it just colored the code, not indent.

Does anyone know how to do this in Visual studio code?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

Click **File** >> **Preferences** >> **Settings**
You will get something like this [image]

### Step 2

The Textbox "search settings" type in `settings.json`
[image] Click `Edit in settings.json`

---

add this in the settings.json just below

---

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
 //Add this below
"files.assocations": {
        "*.ejs": "html"
    },
```

Reload the Visual Code Editor and you are good

Comment: what if there is javascript code, or it 's .js file ? it 's fine with html file but shows errors for EJS brackets in .js file.

Comment: Adding that code snippet in my settings file throws the error unknown configuration settings

Answer (score 1):

try the following link:
[FORMATTING “.EJS” FILE IN VS CODE (VISUAL STUDIO CODE)](https://www.slightedgecoder.com/2018/01/18/formatting-ejs-file-vs-code-visual-studio-code/)

In short, you may need to add this to your settings (ctrl/cmd + ,):

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.ejs": "html"
},
```

Comment: What if there is javascript code, or it 's .js file ? it 's fine with html file but shows errors for EJS brackets in .js file.

Comment: Adding that code snippet in my settings file throws the error unknown configuration settings

Answer (score 0):

Formatting EJS like HTML not work.
Ok, no longer displays an error, but generate a bad formatting.

Examples:

1. Other post:
   [Wrong indentation on EJS files with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399056/wrong-indentation-on-ejs-files-with-vscode)
2. simple code:
   https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/24013
3. see last image, form parameters:
   https://www.sung.codes/blog/2018/formatting-ejs-file-vs-code-visual-studio-code

We need a plugin. "EJS Language Support" plugin it also doesn't work on formatting.