# Wrong indentation on EJS files with VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting, ejs, indentation

I'm facing a problem with EJS files on VSCode, each time I save the file, the formatter applies a wrong indentation.

Below each EJS identifier the next line is shifted to the right missing the correct vertical alignment.

I'm using HTML format for *.ejs and installed the EJS extension from DigitalBrainstem

```
    <% if(locals.metadata && locals.metadata.length>0) { %>
        <% var supplier=metadata[0] %>
            <% } %>

                <main class="site-content">
```

Another example in the picture below

[image: wrong indentation to code]

You can see in the both examples, it looks like a ladder, each line is automatically indented to the right and cannot keep opening/closure code blocks aligned.

Answer (score 21):

Just was looking for the solution to this myself. If installing the ESJ language support plugin didn't work on its own. Go to the settings and search for `Format: templating` you'll see the option to honor some templating language tags. Activate it. This worked for me at least.

Comment: Great solution! In fact checking the "HTML › Format: Templating" option works even without installing the EJS plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

1. Install `EJS language support` plugin
2. Now you have ejs support and snippets, but some tags like

```html
<? for( let item of array ) { ?>
(some data)
<? } ?>
```

are formatted incorrectly (at least with default html formatter).

3. To fix this, you can try set custom delimeter to '?' `ejs.delimeter = '?'`. Now you have correct indentation.
4. To use the snippets with our custom delimeter, you need to edit extension snippets (or add your own): install `Snippets Ranger` plugin, then find needed extension and edit its file. The `Snippets Ranger` is very handy tool.

I hope I helped somebody to setup VSCode for .ejs files

Comment: [Snippets Ranger extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robole.snippets-ranger)